# how to load another activity for honeycomb devices

Tags: android, android-3.0-honeycomb

I have developed an app for smartphones. My activity (`MainActivity`) is extending `TabActivity`.
Now I'm going to create a tablet (honeycomb) layout. For that the `MainActivity` must not extend the `TabActivity`.

Is there a way (intent filters?) to let a honeycomb (api level >= 11) start another Activity as a lower api level device?

Answer (score 0):

The trick is to have three activities. One is the main, and in the main you choose which application activity you start based on whether it is honeycomb or not. In essence something like this (not tested):

```
public class MainAcitivity {
    onCreate(Bundle save) {
        Intent intent;
        if(android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > 10) 
            intent = new Intent(this, HoneycombActivity.class);
        else 
            intent = new Intent(this, PreHoneycombActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

Comment: ok thanks, I did it this way, but I hopped that there is a better solution.

Comment: well a tabactivity is just an activity with a tabhost i think, so you could probably do with just one activity and instead of choosing the activity you could choose between different layouts in a similar way, but thats arguably not really a better solution.